# How to create dataclasses in pytorch from a custom dataset with labels

Tags: pytorch, python-dataclasses

I have created a dataset and saved them in the `dataloader`, there are 10,000 images (`torch.Size([3, 256, 256])`) with 4 labels `[0,1,2,3]` ; hence 4 classes. The labels will be `tensor([])` format.

**Code:**

```
for img, labels in dataloader:
    print(labels)
    print(img[0].shape)
    
    labels_str = str(labels.item())    
    plt.imshow(img[0].permute(1, 2, 0))
    break
```

**Output:**

```
tensor([3])
torch.Size([3, 256, 256])
```

[image]

How to make a pytorch dataclass in order to train a pytorch classifier from this dataset?
As far as I know these are the steps I need to follow :

1. I have to make subfolders in a folder (let's say name `/content/sub_f`) of each class and push the images to each folder according to the label of each image.
2. The subfolders in parent folder `/content/sub_f` are named 0,1,2,3 and the labels of each image is also either of the 4 as shown in the above code.
3. And then create an Pytorch ImageFolder with all the 4 sub-folders.

   `dataset = ImageFolder("/content/sub_f", transform=trans_comp)`

This time the dataset will have 4 classes when we run the code `dataset.classes`

Can someone help?

Comment: Pytorch provides some tutorials: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html. Does it help? In short, you have to instantiate a data loader that wraps the dataset, and then you can iterate over the loader to train your model.

Comment: @hpwww Thanks a lot for the reply, I have actually solved the problem. I'll update the question status and the code in a while, it maybe helpful to people with similar questions in the future.